# How to utilize the golds before HOTS 2.0?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

It seems they have made a lot of changes in HOTS 2.0, especially the currency system. So in the last month of HOTS 1.0, how can I utilize my golds?

Is it better to buy heroes/master skin I like before they are put into loot box? Or I should save all my golds until 2.0?

Comment: Is 2.0 playable yet?  Even in beta?  If not, we can't answer this, and don't allow questions about unreleased content.

Comment: @Frank 2.0 is in beta now, and blizzard has announced the new currency system. I think my question is more related to the current patch.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the update has arrived and pre-update information is no longer useful.

Answer (score 1):

We have some information from the official progression video for HotS 2.0

> 2:26 "Gold continues to be the main currency acquired by playing games, gaining levels and completing quests.  It is primarily used to unlock heroes"

During this statement, we see Valeera being unlocked for 10,000 gold.  This is unchanged from how it works now.

> 1:32 "All current players will have their cumulative experience transferred to this new system without loss"

During this statement, we see an image of level 40 "the lost vikings" merging with a bunch of other heroes of various levels, becoming a level 155 "the lost vikings" player.

Since player level is likely to zoom from the current level cap (20) to the new actual progressed level, there will likely be a plethora of chests unlocked at the time of release of 2.0 - since master skin color variants can come from these chests, it might be better to wait for this event.

> 4:50 "All current skin color variants are now forge-able as individual items within this new system"

If you want all three color variants and are willing to pay your gold now, go for it.  Otherwise, wait for the new system and pay shards to unlock the color variant(s) you want.

From this [other video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-O_e48XhINk) 3:36 "Master skins are no longer a reward for hitting level 10.  The master skins can be achieved at any time and they're just normal skins".

Comment: In Kyle Fergusson's Summit Report (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f_T27gPi3HY) he seems to assert that buying a master skin that you really want with gold now is preferable, because you will get all three tints and will have a reduced chance to open it in your chests when 2.0 goes live. I think the goal is to make it more likely to get other skins in your chests, which are only purchasable with real money presently.

Comment: @JamesCW it won't reduce the chance though.  Duplicates occur and are converted to shards.

Answer (score 0):

As David B said, I will add that Yesterday they will be 4 megapacks which containts 20 heroes each one. The megapacks are "free" for players with 5 accounts lvl or more. It is free because when you reach account lvl 5 on 2.0, you will won 1000 gems and megapacks cost 100 gems and you only can get one of this.

With this megapack, you can invest 100 gems on 20 heroes and then, you can invest the rest of the gold for rerolls on boxes for example.

One tip more: on the boxes, all heroes are gonna be **Legendary** item, so if there are a few heroes that you don't have, it is better having that so you will get a lot ot shards (the currency that you get on boxes if appear duplicate things) instead of a heroe that cost maybe 2000 or 10000.
Keep an eye on this and invest gold for buying cheap heroes to get shards instead of a legendary that cost 2000 gold in the worst case.